# Insert function pointer into map with polymorphic return type

Tags: c++

I didn't know exactly how to title this question. I have a base class and two inheriting classes:

```
class Base {};
class Action : public Base {};
class Title : public Base {};
```

Now let's say I have two functions that return either `Action *` or `Title *`:

```
Action *getAction() { return new Action; }
Title *getTitle() { return new Title; }
```

Is there any way to put these two functions into a map? Like so:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, Base *(*)()> myMap;
    myMap["action"] = getAction;
    myMap["title"] = getTitle;

    return 0;
}
```

Right now I'm getting an error:

```
invalid conversion from `Action* (*)()' to `Base* (*)()'
```

I could change the signature of the functions to always return the base class, and then it would work, but I'm wondering if there is another way to get around this.

Comment: Look into [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), or as an alternative the [Boost function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/function.html) library.

Comment: Would it be possible to get the context of this problem, as in what you're using it for?

Comment: Is using `std::function` the only way to do this? I was hoping to be able to avoid using it.

Comment: Hey @JoachimPileborg, would std::function work here? isnt the return type a template parameter? This would make the 2 functions into different classes right?

Comment: The context is parsing XML, and I could just return `Base *` from the functions or use `std::function`, but I was wondering if there is any way apart from those two.

Comment: @KarthikT The `std::map` data type would be e.g. `std::function<Base*()>`, assign like now: `myMap["action"] = getAction;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use:

```
Base *getAction() { return static_cast<Base *>(new Action); }
Base *getTitle() { return static_cast<Base *>(new Title); }
```

then you will not get this error.

[`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is a polymorphic function pointer wrapper provided by the STL.

Of course, using templates, you could write your own function wrapper that stores a target, passes forward arguments and does conversion. This has already been done though, and you should seriously consider carefully before you decide to roll your own. Unless you enjoy reinventing wheels or have very special requirements.

Comment: So for polymorphic functions there is only `std::function' or the equivalent Boost library available as a solution? (i.e. Is that all there is?)

Comment: Thanks, I'm satisfied now I think :-)

Answer (score 1):

As a proof of concept I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

struct A
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct B : public A
{
    void f() { std::cout << "B::f\n"; }
};

struct C : public A
{
    void f() { std::cout << "C::f\n"; }
};

B* getB() { return new B; }
C* getC() { return new C; }

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<A*()>> m;
    m["b"] = getB;
    m["c"] = getC;

    m["b"]()->f();
    m["c"]()->f();
}
```

It leaks memory, but it [works](http://ideone.com/Jj6bMP).